# Multithreaded Java Application uses only one core and gets stuck

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, tomcat, tomcat7

- We are running a multithreaded java application in a Linux  environment (vm). We have 30 cores. Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
- Linux version 2.6.32-279.5.1.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-004.build.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Tue Jul 24 
  13:57:35 EDT 2012
- We are running our application inside Tomcat (7.0.42)
- What we see is that sometimes only one of the processors gets used around 100% and in those situations the application becomes non responsive and needs to be restarted, the rest of the cores appear to be completely idle, while one of them seems to be intensively used.
- We got a few thread dumps (we had to get them using kill -3 as jstack was getting connection errors), although they don’t show any obvious deadlock or issue.
- When the application becomes non responsive we can’t attach to it using visual vm or jconsole.
- We checked this article in java-monitor.com http://java-monitor.com/forum/showthread.php?t=317
- In a couple of cases, we observed this behaviour within minutes of restart.
- Following some of the instructions provided below, we identified the thread that was using the CPU, it was the "VM thread".
- We updated the jvm to the lastest available version: 
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode)
  Since then we haven't been able to see the issue, again, although in some cases it previously took weeks to appear.
- A couple of times during the last months we also got the below message  after a few minutes of restarting our application

  ```
  #
  # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
  #
  #  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fbe71501d19, pid=18022, tid=139946328471296
  #
  # JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_45-b18) (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
  # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.45-b08 mixed mode linux-amd64 )
  # Problematic frame:
  # J  java.lang.management.ThreadInfo.<init>(Ljava/lang/Thread;ILjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Thread;JJJJ[Ljava/lang/StackTraceElement;[Ljava/lang/Object;[I[Ljava/lang/Object;)V
  #
  #
  # Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
  #
  # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
  #   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
  #
  ```

on a different case:

```
    #
    # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
    #
    #  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f1c2f0debec, pid=16493, tid=139756998551296
    #
    # JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_45-b18) (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
    # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.45-b08 mixed mode linux-amd64 )
    # Problematic frame:
    # V  [libjvm.so+0x756bec]  PhaseIdealLoop::build_loop_late_post(Node*)+0x13c
    #
    # Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
    #
    # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
    #   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
    #
```

I would appreciate any idea or suggestion.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's hard to even try to answer your question because a lot of information is missing. I have a few ideas though, 1. how about using tomcat's Stuck Thread Detection Valve? http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html#Stuck_Thread_Detection_Valve 2. What happens when you try to kill tomcat using the shutdown port? Does it die normally?

Comment: Try using `top` in thread mode to identify the ID of the thread that is spinning out of control.  Then if you can get a Java threads-stacks dump, you can map the `top` ID to the ID in the dump, and hopefully that will tell you which thread is out of control (and what method(s) it is in) which may give you a path forward. The approach is explained more here: http://code.nomad-labs.com/2010/11/18/identifying-which-java-thread-is-consuming-most-cpu/

Comment: Looks like a JVM bug. Try to use different version (OpenJDK, Java8). Prepare a compact test and submit a bug report to Oracle. Try to run on another processor architecture (Intel<->AMD). Isolate the bug and make a workaround.

Comment: Any way to access the JVM with jconsole to see the threads and there stack traces live?  See: http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/jconsole-jmx-remote-access-on-tomcat/

Comment: @Malt thanks a lot for the suggestion, we will try this next time that we see the issue. Unfortunately it seems to be a random error that we saw continuously during a day, but later on it seemed to dissapear on its own. A month later we saw the same issue.

Comment: @MikeClark thanks a lot, as per my answer to Malt, we will try it next time this happens.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov we also though this could be a possibility and what we are doing is upgrading to the latest available version of java 7.

Comment: @Gray as per the original description unfortunately the server was being no responsive up to the point that it was impossible to get a connection to it from either jconsole or visualvm